# How to log in different users in Symfony under the same Behat scenario

Tags: symfony, authentication, multiple-instances, behat, mink

I have a simple Scenario.

- Given Bob logs in
- And Alice logs in
- Bob edits Article 1 and Saves it.
- Alice edits Article 1 and saves but should see that Bob already
  did changes.
- Alice should reload -> Alice sees changes  ...

Honorable mentions : [How to authenticate once in Behat environment](https://medium.com/@robinvdvleuten/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink-cfca29596d94#.c7tcm5qnm) and [How to simulate two users](http://swdesigns.co.uk/2012/07/multiple-sessions-with-behat-mink-and-selenium2/).

My problem is that I have to Authenticate users in different sessions but the kernel always returns same session name/id. What I don't know is how can I authenticate users in sessions named according to the Mink Session name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use mink functionality and create a few sessions inside behat environment.

So, from the very beginning you have one default session:

```
$this->getSession();
```

And you can register new session with exact driver.

New instance of needed driver. f.e. GoutteDriver.

```
$goutteDriver = new GoutteDriver();
$sess = new \Behat\Mink\Session($goutteDriver);
$this->getMink()->registerSession('newSession', $sess);
```

And then use it in your steps:

```
$this->getSession('newSession')->getPage();
```

But the new session won't has any params from your behat.yml. So take care about that. You can get all the params from

```
$this->getMinkParameters();
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but when I try to Authenticate users they are assigned to PHPSSID and not FOO for example.

Comment: So, you are using Symfony2 session by default, right? and so you are creating new mink session with symfony2 driver? If its doesn't help - then you need to play around with $this->getContainer()->get('session'); which has lots of get and set methods. And I'll try to investigate and write you back.